# Explanation of finding the 4th term of a Geometric Sequence

Tags: geometric-series

I completed a problem but it seems as if I got the wrong answer. I would like to see what error I made so I do not make the same mistake again. The questions goes as follows :

"If the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric series is given by $S_n = 1 - (-2)^n $, find the 4th term of the series."

I inputted 4 as n, as it stated it is the 4th term, and I got the following.

$S_4 = 1 - (-2)^4$

$S_4 = 1 + 16 $

$S_4 = 17 $

This answer was marked wrong, and the correct answer was -24. Can someone explain to me how the answer -24 can be obtained from this? Thanks.

Comment: The sum of a series is different from the term of a series. The question wants $a_4$ and not $S_4$.

Comment: Surely $S_4=-15$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Inserting it into my calculator, I was given -16 for $-2^4$. Checking it over, I see it's actually -15. Weird. Now if I got -15 and followed the strategy given by David Quinn below... it would have given -24. Bummer.

Comment: If a_n is the associated sequence, S_4 = S_3 + a_4 so S_4 -S_3 = a_4

Comment: And to answer your calculator issue, use parentheses

Answer (score 4):

Hint........you need $S_4-S_3$

Answer (score 1):

$$S_n=u_1\frac {1-q^n}{1-q}$$

$$=3\frac {1-(-2)^n}{1-(-2)} $$

thus
$$u_1=3$$
and
$$q=-2$$

finally
$$u_4=u_1q^3=-24$$